# Unity TCP client: connection to a server

Tags: unity-game-engine, tcp, ip, client

I have a hardware that streams data to a windows server, and I have IP and port of this server. Now I want to connect unity app as a TCP client to this server. I have tried many solutions, but still have hard time to figure out best way to do this. Any help is highly appreciated. One issue that I have with current tutorials is that most of them define a unity server and try to connect another unity app as client and mostly based on localhost. However, I just want to connect a unity app as a TCP client to a server which I have IP and port.

Warm regards,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uAyA.jpg)

Comment: [`var client = new TcpClient("IP.ad.dre.ss", portNumber);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.-ctor#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient__ctor_System_String_System_Int32_) ...?

Comment: First, You need to open port on windows server, and you need a service which as you point can be the Unity Server itself. Windows server does not understand any thing beside windows and management stuff, unless you turn the feature on, or provide one, which in your case is not available by default. Second, In stackoverflow, you need to share your data as direct as possible, like sharing the image within the page (You may not have access at first) and it is important to provide some code that explains how and for what data, you are trying to do that, with providing some codes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, at the top of your script:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
```

Then, create an instance of TcpClient and begin the connection:

```cs
socket = new TcpClient
{
    // dataBufferSize is in bytes
    ReceiveBufferSize = dataBufferSize,
    SendBufferSize = dataBufferSize
};

socket.BeginConnect(ip, port, ConnectCallback, socket);
```

In `ConnectCallback()`:

```cs
private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    socket.EndConnect(asyncResult);
    if (!socket.Connected) return;
    // stream is a NetworkStream you should declare somewhere
    stream = socket.GetStream();
    // receiveBuffer is a byte[] you should declare somewhere
    receiveBuffer = new byte[dataBufferSize];
    stream.BeginRead(receiveBuffer, 0, dataBufferSize, ReceiveCallback, null);
}
```

In `ReceiveCallback()`:

```cs
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    try
    {
        int byteLength = stream.EndRead(asyncResult);
        if (byteLength <= 0)
        {
            // Disconnect client
            return;
        }

        // Transfer data from receiveBuffer to data variable for handling
        byte[] data = new byte[byteLength];
        Array.Copy(receiveBuffer, data, byteLength);
        // Handle data in any way you want to

        // BeginRead again so you can keep receiving data
        stream.BeginRead(receiveBuffer, 0, dataBufferSize, ReceiveCallback, null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error receiving TCP data: {e.Message}");
    }
}
```

I got this information from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh8XaC0Y5MA&list=PLXkn83W0QkfnqsK8I0RAz5AbUxfg3bOQ5).